Failed to create /home/maksio/.config/discord/SingletonLock: Input/output error (5) when starting Discord
Recently, I have moved my Arch Linux /home directory to an SMB share. Everything else works, but Discord fails to start with this error:
Failed to create /home/maksio/.config/discord/SingletonLock: Input/output error (5)

I tried symlinking /home/maksio/.config/discord to /discord in order to fix this, but that failed with:
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/maksio/.config/discord': Input/output error

The command I used was:
ln -sf /discord /home/maksio/.config/discord

The /home folder is mounted like this in /etc/fstab:
//Maksio-SERV/secure/user\040folders/arch /home cifs credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,noperm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,auto,nofail 0 0

The SMB mount is hosted by samba.
How can I get Discord to work again? (preferably without putting /home back where it was)

Observation, research: if creation succeeded, SingletonLock would be a "creatively used" symlink (explanation). So it seems you just cannot create symlinks inside the SMB mount.

@KamilMaciorowski Does that mean Discord will not work? Or is there a workaround?

It means I checked Discord in my Linux and I can tell you the file is a symlink (and not e.g. a unix domain socket), so now you can research if you can make your SMB support Linux symlinks, not only in hope to make your workaround work, but in hope to make Discord just work. So maybe this question (but note it's Operation not supported there, Input/output error here). Filing a bug report for Discord may also help. IMO the program shall create the lock file in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/discord/ or so, not in its config directory.
